# crypt() function in C not working

Tags: c

The following is my file named crack.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>

void execute(char *alpha)
{
    char *beta = crypt(alpha);
    printf("%s", beta);
}

int main(int argc, string argv[]){

        ....

        execute(argv[1]);
        else{
            printf("You submitted %d command line arguments.  That's an issue.  You need to submit exactly one.", argc);
            return 1;
        }
}
```

The following is what I type into the command line:

```
jharvard@appliance (~/Dropbox/hacker2): clang -o crack -lcrypt crack.c
```

The following is what the command line spits back out at me:

```
crack.c:8:19: warning: implicit declaration of function 'crypt' is
invalid in
      C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    string beta = crypt(alpha);
                  ^ crack.c:8:12: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing
      'string' (aka 'char *') with an expression of type 'int'
      [-Wint-conversion]
    string beta = crypt(alpha);
           ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~ 2 warnings generated.
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: `else` without `if`? o.O

Comment: Add `#include <crypt.h>`. Also, the code presented won't compile: else without an if and missing open bracket in main.

Comment: @haccks There's an if , it just didn't copy/paste for whatever reason.  Sorry, will fix.

Comment: `_printf("You submitted %d command line arguments.  That's an issue.  You need to submit exactly one.", argc);` If you do not submit any further argument, `argc` will be `1` storing the name of your outfile. Think about s.th. like `argc - 1`.

Comment: `crypt` signature doesn't match the way you're calling it. What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: This may or may not be your problem, but, `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600` instead of just `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE`, and move it above *all* the headers.  It doesn't do anything if it isn't at the very top of the file.

Comment: C does not have a **string** data type. If the compiler isn't spitting up on it, you're probably actually compiling as C++. C++ is a different (though related) language.

Comment: @PhilPerry I'm guessing his `cs50.h` does some fugly typedeffing of `string` as `char *`.

Comment: @Phil Perry The error msg "'string' (aka 'char *') with an expression of type 'int'" appears to understand `string` as a `char *`.

Comment: Still, it would be best to understand that it's not standard (or at least, "traditional") C, and may not be widely portable.

Comment: @PhilPerry Totally agree about that (hence the fugly part). I don't think it's the problem though.

Comment: Of all the comments posted, the one that is directly related to the given error is the one from @JohnnyMopp : a failure for the compiler to know what `crypt` is, and thus implicitly assuming it is a function taking an unknown number of parameters and returning `int`. Similar to the problem of casting `malloc()` without including `stdlib.h`. At least this time there is no cast, so the compiler yells. Further, it is the only one backed by the posted (albeit broken) code from the OP.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and I realized that changing the header

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
```

by

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <crypt.h>
```

makes disapear the error in compilation time

Answer (score 1):

The function signature of [`crypt`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/crypt.html) is:

```
char * crypt (const char *key, const char *salt)
```

It seems that you forgot one parameter! So your line:

```
string beta = crypt(alpha);
```

Should be something like that:

```
string beta = crypt(alpha, salt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the define and include for crypt as the very first lines at the top of your file before any other includes.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
```